# What is the difference between str() and " " in python?

Tags: python, string, difference

While learning python, I could not find the difference between the use of `str()` and `" "`.

First code
[image]
Second code
[image]

Comment: code as text please...

Comment: `str` _converts_ any type to string. `"xxx"` is _already_ as string.

Answer (score 2):

With `str()` function you are changing the number type to String but with `""` you just pass the String.

`str(3.14) # 3.14` is a number and your are converting it into String.

`"3.14"` is an String value.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if you had a variable

```
pi=3.14
```

then

```
str(pi)
```

would give the result 3.14

whereas

```
 "pi"
```

would give the result pi. The `str()` function converts something to its string form. Whereas simple quotes will return the word itself.

Answer (score 0):

`str()` returns a string representation of an object, while quotation marks indicate the value is a string. To see the difference, consider the following:

```
x = 3.14
print("x")      #outputs the character x
print(str(x))   #string representation of the value of object x
```

In the first `print()`, the actual character 'x' is output. This has nothing to with the variable x. However, in the second `print()`, the value of the object x is converted to a string, so '3.14' is output.

Answer (score -2):

There is no difference between the two.  The program will run the same.  CodeCademy requires that you use the skills (functions and methods) that it teaches you in that step in order to progress to the next one.  The python script doesn't do anything differently, but the CodeCademy code analyzer notices that you didn't accomplish the task the way they wanted you too.

Comment: Please see the above answers for why there is a definite difference between the two.

Comment: There's actually a _huge_ difference. `str(test)` may return `"Adam"`, which is definitely not equal to `"test"`.

Comment: In the examples provided above, they both get the same result.  Yes, the quotations and the function have different outputs, but I don't believe that, that was the question.  OP wanted to know what they were doing wrong in reference to CodeCademy